# byte compile file-local variables

Tags: byte-compilation, file-local-variables

Is it possible to access a user-defined file-local variable during byte-compilation?

As an example, I am trying to get this code to work:

```
--- testfilelocals.el ---
;; -*- my-file-local: "foo" -*-

(defun testfilelocals ()
  (eval-when-compile 
    my-file-local))
```

which fails with a compiler error

```
testfilelocals.el:5:5:Error: Symbol's value as variable is void: my-file-local
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code in `bytecomp.el`, one can see that only safe file-local variables are read (see the relevant part of the file below).

This means that if you declare your variable as safe for file-local use, it should be read when you compile your file. You can for example evaluate the following piece of code before you byte-compile the file:

```lisp
(put 'my-file-local 'safe-local-variable 'stringp)
```

---

For reference, here is the relevant part of `bytecomp.el`:

```lisp
(let ((buffer-file-name filename)
      (dmm (default-value 'major-mode))
      ;; Ignore unsafe local variables.
      ;; We only care about a few of them for our purposes.
      (enable-local-variables :safe)
      (enable-local-eval nil))
```

Comment: Thanks for quoting `bytecomp.el`. I was surprised to find out that loading the uncompiled source file with `load-file` even after setting the `safe-local-variable` property will result in a `void-variable` error when calling `(testfilelocals)`, i.e. there is a disparity between compiled and uncompiled code. The quoted code (especially the comment) indicates that availability of file-local variables at compile time may be an unintended side-effect of the compiler implementation. I planned to modify the behaviour of a macro with those, which doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you did not specify major mode where the variables are used:

```
;; -*- mode: Lisp; my-file-local: "foo" -*-
```

Most major modes [reset all variables](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/emacs/html_node/emacs_486.html) upon initialization.

Comment: Actually, I don't think so: trying to byte compile an example file where the mode is specified shows that it doesn't get rid of the problem. Still, your idea was good: the sources of `bytecomp.el` show that care has been taken to activate `emacs-lisp-mode` without altering file-local variables.

Comment: "...I don't think so..." in that case please submit corrections to the manual.

Comment: Sorry if my wording was unclear. I'm not saying that what you (or the manual) say is wrong... I'm just saying that I don't think it is the reason why the OP's file-local variable is not set during byte-compilation. You (and the manual), are correct when saying that "most modes kill all local variables as part of their initialization", but - if I understand it correctly - the reason why the OP's file-local variable is not set during byte-compilation is not that it has been killed, but rather that it has never been read in the first place since it was not safe.